# R: create new matrix with outcomes from mathematical operations within another matrix through loops

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, apply

I am trying to generate a function that conducts various mathematical operations within a matrix and stores the outcomes of these operations in a new matrix with similar dimensions.
Here's an example matrix (a lot of silly computations in it to get sufficient variability in the data)

```
test<-matrix(1:290,nrow=10,ncol=29) ; colnames(test)<-1979+seq(1,29)
rownames(test)<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")
test[,4]<-rep(8)
test[7,]<-seq(1,29)
test[c(3,5,9),]<-test[c(3,5,9),] * 1/2
test[,c(4,6,8,9,10,15,16,18)]<-test[,c(4,6,8,9,10,15,16,18)]*1/3
```

I want for instance to be able to calculate the difference between the value in (a,1999) and the average of the 3 values before (a, 1999). This needs to be flexible and for every rowname (firm) and every column (year).

The code I am trying to build looks something like this (I guess):

```
for(year in 1:29)
  for (k in 1:10)
      qw<-matrix((test[k, year] + 1/3*(- test[k, year-1] - test[k,year -2] - test[k, year-3])), nrow=10, ncol=29)
```

When I run it, this code generates a matrix but the value in that matrix is always the one for the last calculation (i.e. 20 in my example) while every matrix value should be stored in qw.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this (maybe via an apply function)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a matrix `qw` in every iteration. Each new matrix overwrites the previous one. Here's how to do what I think you would like to do, altough I didn't know how you want to handle the first 3 years.

```
qw <- matrix(nrow=10, ncol=29)
colnames(qw)<-1979+seq(1,29)
rownames(qw)<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")
for(year in 4:29){
  for (k in 1:10){
    qw[k, year] <- (test[k, year] + 1/3*(- test[k, year-1] - test[k,year -2] - test[k, year-3]))
  }
}
qw
```

In R, it is usually a bad idea to use loops, since there are much more efficient functions. Here is the R way of doing this, using the package `zoo`.

```
require(zoo)
qw <- matrix(nrow=10, ncol=29)
colnames(qw)<-1979+seq(1,29)
rownames(qw)<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")
qw[,4:29] <- test[,4:29]-t(head(rollmean(t(test), 3),-1))
qw
```

Comment: Thanks @shadow. The zoo package works brilliantly. Thanks as well for showing me how to make my code with loops work. Both will be hugely helpful in my future R endeavours!

Comment: can you think of any reason why the function using the zoo package seems to be less efficient than the loop? With the loop I can get the results for my actual matrix (100.000 * 30) in about 15 seconds. With the zoo package, the STOP sign persists after more than 5 minutes...

Comment: It seems that `rollmean` is efficient only for univariate time series and not for matrices. Not entirely sure why, but you could probably find out from the code of `zoo:::rollmean.zoo`. It seems to use `lapply` and `merge` to deal with multivariate time series.

Comment: Depending on the size of the matrices, my benchmarktests show that 
`for (k in 1:nrow(test)){
  qw[k, 4:ncol(test)] <- test[k,4:ncol(test)]-head(rollmean(test[k,], 3),-1)
}` 
could be the fastest solution.

Comment: Thanks again. Your final suggestions without the two transformations works about as fast as the more intuitive loop for my dataset (which is a matrix). thanks for your expertise and help!